# JSP writing to the response with a filter

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I would like to include the jQuery library for every page by modifying the response. Here it is:

This is in the Filter:

```
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   out.println("<head><script src=\"http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js\"></script></head>");
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

It works just fine but when I want to write something else to the response with a servlet then get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What does the servlet do? What's the full stack trace of the exception? Why are you doing that in a filter, and not in the JSP? If all your pages should look the same, then you should use a templating engine (Sitemesh, Tiles, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the html code to the file and use servlet dispatcher method include that file. See more about it in [javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher#include(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29)

**`included.html`:**

```
<head><script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script></head>
```

**filter code:**

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("included.html").include(request, respose);
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing the response in a web application, you can use either `response.getWriter()` or `response.getOutputStream()`, but not both. So you should :

- either use `response.getWriter()` in the servlet
- or use `response.getOutputStream()` in your filter